# How do I make my program remember the values of integers in Objective C - Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my program I am trying to set a value for bucket1&2 that is then outputted to a label
in previous actions I am setting a value for bucket1 and bucket2, that has been outputted to a label and when I push the button "bucket1trans" I want it to use the previous values to make a new value for bucket2, then output it to a label

What I've done is below

```
int bucket1;
int bucket2;

-(IBAction)bucket1trans:(id)sender{
bucket2 = bucket2+bucket1;
label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", bucket2];
}
```

I am not sure if I should be using int as my program doesn't seem to remember the previous that was set for my int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code you have shown isn't sufficient for debugging what the problem is.
But the general solution are:

1) use a static variable for your bucket variables.

For Ex:

```
static int bucket1;
static int bucket2;
```

2) If you want to use the same value over the program, define it in the appDelegate and access it using the shared instance of the appDelegate of your program.

```
<Your AppDelegate Name> *appDelegate = (<Your AppDelegate Name>*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
int bucket1 = appDelegate.bucket1;
```

In your appDelegate, you need to synthesize the variable in order to access it using . operator.

For Example:

in your appDelegate.h file,

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) int bucket1;
```

in your appDelegate.m

```
@synthesize bucket1;
```

Answer (score 0):

take a variable in app delegate.Use that wherever you need.